# Does STARTSWITH on Cosmos partition keys optimize "fan-out" of cross-partition queries?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Microsoft makes it clear that cross-partition queries "fan-out" the query to each partition ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container#cross-partition-query)):

> The following query doesn't have a filter on the partition key (DeviceId). Therefore, it must fan-out to all physical partitions where it is run against each partition's index:

So I am curious if that "fan-out" can be optimized by doing a range query on a partition key, such as STARTSWITH.

To test it, I created a small Cosmos DB with seven documents:

```json
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix1:",
    "id": "item1a"
},
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix1:",
    "id": "item1b"
},
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix1:",
    "id": "item1c"
},
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix1X:",
    "id": "item1d"
},
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix2:",
    "id": "item2a"
},
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix2:",
    "id": "item2b"
},
{
    "partitionKey": "prefix3:",
    "id": "item3a"
}
```

It has the default indexing policy with partition key "/partitionKey". Then I ran a bunch of queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.partitionKey, 'prefix1')
-- Actual Request Charge: 2.92 RUs
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'prefix1:' OR c.partitionKey = 'prefix1X:'
-- Actual Request Charge: 3.02 RUs
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.partitionKey, 'prefix1:')
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'prefix1:'
-- Each Query Has Actual Request Charge: 2.89 RUs
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.partitionKey, 'prefix2')
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'prefix2:'
-- Each Query Has Actual Request Charge: 2.86 RUs
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.partitionKey, 'prefix3')
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'prefix3:'
-- Each Query Has Actual Request Charge: 2.83 RUs
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'prefix2:' OR c.partitionKey = 'prefix3:'
-- Actual Request Charge: 2.99 RUs
```

The request charges were consistent when re-running the queries. And the pattern of charge growth seemed consistent with the result set and query complexity, with exception of maybe the 'OR' queries. However, then I tried this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c
-- Actual Request Charge: 2.35 RUs
```

And the basic fan-out to all partitions is even faster than targeting a specific partition, even with an equality operator. I don't understand how this can be.

All this being said, my sample database is extremely small with only seven documents. The query set is probably not big enough to trust the results.

So, if I had millions of documents, would STARTSWITH(c.partitionKey, 'prefix') be more optimized than fanning out to all partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you scale, you get fewer "[logical partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#logical-partitions)" per "[physical partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#physical-partitions)", until eventually each partition key value has its own physical partition.

So:

> if I had millions of documents, would STARTSWITH(c.partitionKey, 'prefix') be more optimized than fanning out to all partitions?

Both queries would fan-out across multiple partitions.

And I'm pretty sure that since "Azure Cosmos DB uses hash-based partitioning to spread logical partitions across physical partitions", there's no locality between partition keys with a common prefix, and  each STARTSWITH query will have to fan-out across all the physical partitions.

Comment: I understand that STARTSWITH will potentially scan 'multiple' partitions. So to rephrase my question -- will using STARTSWITH prevent scanning partitions which do not match the STARTSWITH filter? I want the scans to happen only on partitions which match the filter, and not scan partitions which do not match the filter.

Comment: no, why would it? how it would know about that?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am not sure I understand the question. Basically, Cosmos service would have to see the query that there is a condition on partition key, just like it would with an equality operator, and parse it out to conclude the set of partitions the rest of the query applies to. Or is anything more than an equality compare too complicated for Cosmos, and instead it just fans out, and each partition will scan all documents even though the query doesn't even apply to it.

Comment: Hash partitioning generally prevents range scanning, as the partitions aren’t stored in order.

Comment: I have to admit I do not understand what hash partitioning has to do with it, or why hash partitioning would prevent range scanning, or even how partitions are stored is relevant. From my feeble mind, Cosmos would have to iterate the key of every logical partition to determine if the filter condition is satisfied, once it is satisfied then it will scan that partition. It cannot use the hash of the key in STARTSWITH to do that because the filter condition doesn't contain the whole key. It seems OR would be faster because the filter condition contains the whole key and can then hash.

Comment: I think your answer is correct and my initial question was coming from a false premise about the "fanning" as I was thinking it was fanning to logical partitions (because they are identified by the partition key), but the fanning is a physical routing. A whole partition key (not a partial with STARTSWITH) would allow Cosmos to target the physical set of logical partitions to run the query on, but since I am using STARTSWITH it cannot ascertain that and must fan out to all physical set of local partitions. My question's example only has one physical partition so it is a bad example.

Comment: I am starting to understand that all logical partitions on a single physical partition use the same "index" and therefore its the physical routing that is important. My reason for asking is I was trying to abuse partition keys to give me multiple namespaces of data, but each namespace data distributed across multiple partitions for performance. For example, 100 logical partitions for doc-type-A, and 50 logical partitions for doc-type-B, and then when querying I only need to target the partitions containing the specific doc-type. The docs don't need to be in the same logical partition.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to determine if there is any benefit of this approach myself, and according to the answers it does not seem like there is.

I did just learn about the new hierarchical partition keys feature that is in private preview and seems to address the problem we are trying to solve:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/hierarchical-partition-keys-private-preview/

> Hierarchical partition keys are now available in private preview for
> the Azure Cosmos DB Core (SQL) API. With hierarchical partition keys,
> also known as sub-partitioning, you can now natively partition your
> container with up to three levels of partition keys. This enables more
> optimal partitioning strategies for multi-tenant scenarios or
> workloads that would otherwise use synthetic partition keys. Instead
> of having to choose a single partition key – which often leads to
> performance trade-offs – you can now use up to three keys to further
> sub-partition your data, enabling more optimal data distribution and
> higher scale.

Since this allows up to 3 keys it could solve the problem by breaking up the prefixes into separate keys or at least further optimize it if there are more then 3.

**Example**
(Usage example from link):
https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/HierarchicalPartitionKeysFeedbackGroup#net-v3-sdk-2

```
// Get the full partition key path
var id = "0a70accf-ec5d-4c2b-99a7-af6e2ea33d3d"; 
var fullPartitionkeyPath = new PartitionKeyBuilder()
        .Add("Contoso") //TenantId
        .Add("Alice") //UserId
        .Build();
var itemResponse = await containerSubpartitionByTenantId_UserId.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(id, fullPartitionkeyPath);
```

**Considerations**

From the preview link it looks like you would need to opt in to the preview and create a new container

> New containers only – all keys must be specified upon container
> creation

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics#partitioning-and-partition-keys) suggest that there is *some* efficiency

> With Azure Cosmos DB, typically queries perform in the following order from fastest/most efficient to slower/less efficient.
>
> - GET on a single partition key and item key
> - Query with a filter clause on a single partition key
> - Query without an equality or range filter clause on any property
> - Query without filters